# Adcolony delegate not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, adcolony

I am trying to add Adcolony in my app. Here is my code:

```
[AdColony configureWithAppID:myAppID
                         zoneIDs:@[myZoneID]
                        delegate:self
                         logging:YES];
[AdColony playVideoAdForZone:myZoneID withDelegate:self withV4VCPrePopup:YES andV4VCPostPopup:YES];

-(void)onAdColonyV4VCReward:(BOOL)success currencyName:(NSString *)currencyName currencyAmount:(int)amount inZone:(NSString *)zoneID
{  
    if (success) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

The problem is the delegate method `onAdColonyV4VCReward:` is never getting called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for us was to set the app to "client side" on the Dashboard.

Comment: Can you please attach an image?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. We have an Ad Manager, I don't have access to this dashboard.